# Special property of flat spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Eschenburg's paper Local convexity and nonnegative curvature — Gromov's proof of the sphere theorem recently. And I meet a little question. In 6.1 he said: let $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ be the euclidean $n$-space. Let $S$ be a connected hypersurface which is $\varepsilon$-convex with respect to the unit normal field $N$ on $S$. A special property of the flat space is
$$
D^2 d(X, X) \geqq(d+\frac{1}{\varepsilon})^{-1}\|X\|^2 \text { for any } X \perp \nabla d
$$
at any point where $d$ is smooth, also on $M_{+}^{\prime}$. I can't understand why this property holds on $M_{+}^{\prime}$, where $d>0$ and smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that here $d$ is the signed distance to $S$.
So the $\varepsilon$-convexity can be written as
$$D^2d(X,X)\ge \varepsilon\cdot |X|^2$$
for any tangenet vector to $S$.

The level set $d=\ell$ is $\ell$-equidistant hypersurface, say $S_\ell$.
So, Eschenburg says that in the Euclidean space, $S_\ell$ is $1/(\ell+\tfrac1\varepsilon)$-convex which is easy to check.